# F# and J# are they same?

Tags: .net, f#, j#

I see an `F#` compiler with MS Visual Studio 2010, I heard about `J#`, are they the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

J# was a product which took Java 1.1.4 code and produced IL which (combined with assemblies to provide the libraries for Java 1.1.4) allowed some Java code to be built and run on .NET. It's been discontinued, and I never saw much sign of it being very widely used - even if you wanted to run Java code, by the time .NET came out most Java developers were writing Java 2 code, so their programs weren't supported by J# anyway.

[F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/cc742182) is a functional language with object-oriented features which compiles to IL and runs on .NET. Very cool stuff :) F# is very much alive and kicking.

Answer (score 3):

No, J# was a java compiler for .NET that Microsoft produced years ago. It discontinued it.

From the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J_Sharp)

> Visual J# (pronounced 'jay-sharp') programming language is a
>   discontinued transitional language for programmers of Java and Visual
>   J++ languages, so they may use their existing knowledge and
>   applications on .NET Framework.

F# instead is an "impure" functional (+ imperative) language of Microsoft for .NET.

From the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29)

> F# (pronounced F Sharp) is a multi-paradigm programming language,
>   targeting the .NET Framework, that encompasses functional programming
>   as well as imperative and object-oriented programming disciplines. It
>   is a variant of ML and is largely compatible with the OCaml
>   implementation.

Answer (score 3):

They are completely different languages.

`J#` basically allows using the Java syntax to develop under .NET Framework and `F#` is completely different and new [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) language

Answer (score 2):

No, they are completely different.  J# is a .net version of Java, while F# is a new language developed by Microsoft that is called a functional language.